# How to sum a function applied to each element in a range?

Tags: arrays, google-apps-script, google-sheets, sum, google-sheets-formula

In Google Sheets, I have a function defined in a script:

```
function MIHPNN(level,multiplier,a,b) {

  return ((a+100)/100)*2*(300*multiplier+(50*(level-1))*b)
}
```

And I have a column B with level values.

How do I sum the values of the function applied to each cell of column B?

I tried `SUM(MIHPNN(B:B,0.5,2,2))`
 which doesn't work, of course.

I tried `ArrayFormula(SUM(MIHPNN(B:B,0.5,2,2)))`
 which doesn't work, to my surprise.

Is there a way to make this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

perhaps drop the scripting...

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SUM(((ROW(A2)+100)/100)*2*(300*(ROW(M1)/2)+(50* 
 (INDIRECT("B1:B"&COUNTA(B:B))-1))*ROW(B2))))
```

[image: 0]

- a = `ROW(A2)` = 2
- b = `ROW(B2)` = 2
- multiplier = `(ROW(M1)/2)` = 0.5
- level = `INDIRECT("B1:B"&COUNTA(B:B))` = B1:B3